# SPSS different numbers with Define multiple response set and Multiple response frequency

Tags: spss

I am working a lot with multiple response sets and I would like to use custom tables. But the problem is that if I use `MRSETS` or `MULT RESPONSE` the frequencies differ from one another.

With `MULTI RESPONSE`:

```
MULT RESPONSE GROUPS=$XS10Q2_1_multi 'Variable label' (
XS10Q2_1_cod
XS10Q2_2_cod
XS10Q2_3_cod
XS10Q2_4_cod
XS10Q2_5_cod
(1,999))
  /FREQUENCIES=$XS10Q2_1_multi.
```

With `MRSETS`:

```
MRSETS
  /MCGROUP NAME=$XS10Q2_1_multi LABEL='Variable label' VARIABLES=XS10Q2_1_cod XS10Q2_2_cod 
    XS10Q2_3_cod XS10Q2_4_cod XS10Q2_5_cod
  /DISPLAY NAME=[$XS10Q2_1_multi].

CTABLES
  /VLABELS VARIABLES=$XS10Q2_1_multi DISPLAY=LABEL
  /TABLE $XS10Q2_1_multi [COUNT F40.0, COLPCT.COUNT PCT40.1]
  /CATEGORIES VARIABLES=$XS10Q2_1_multi ORDER=A KEY=VALUE EMPTY=INCLUDE.
```

What could I be missing here?

Thank you for all your help in advance!

***EDIT**

With `MULT RESPONSE`:

```
Case Summary(b)
Cases
Valid       Missing     Total
                    N          Percent  N      Percent  N       Percent    
$XS10Q2_1_multia    329        32,4%    686    67,6%    1015    100,0%


$XS10Q2_1_multi Frequencies
Responses       Percent of Cases
    N   Percent
a   113 29,2%   34,4%
b   101 26,2%   30,9%
c   93  23,9%   28,2%
d   33  8,5%    10,0%
e   26  6,6%    7,8%
DK  22  5,6%    6,6%
Total  387  100,0%  117,9%
```

With `MRSETS` and `CTABLES`:

```
Count   Column N %
a   103 31,4%
b   95  28,9%
c   92  27,9%
d   32  9,6%
e   24  7,4%
DK  12  3,6%
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the two sets have different variables.  If the real ones have the same variables, check that the missing value treatments are the same.  Then post the output and ideally the data.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I copied wrong syntax so i changed that. No variable has any missing values. I have posted output in the original question as there is no room here in a comment. And in both cases dataset has an equal weight.

Answer (score 0):

CTABLES has two ways of treating responses: you can count duplicate responses or not.  If you were tabulating, say, magazines read, you wouldn't want to count duplicates while if you were tabulating cars owned, you might.  This only affects multiple category sets, which appears to be what you have.

You control this with the MRSETS subcommand or the checkbox on Options.  This affects the RESPONSES statistic, but the COUNT statistic always ignores duplicates.

See if that setting resolves the difference.  If not and you want to send the data to me (jkpeck@gmail.com), I can take a look.